# osMutexAcquire() crashes stm32f103c8

Tags: multithreading, mutex, stm32, rtos, hal

I am using stm32f103c8 with CMSIS-RTOS2, my program crashes whene i call osMutexAcquire()
The functions of my threads

```
void child_task1()
{

    while(1)
    {
        osMutexAcquire(myMutex1,osWaitForever);
        _send("Hello form child1\n");
        osMutexRelease(myMutex2);
        osDelay(100);
    }
}

void child_tas2()
{

    while(1)
    {
        osMutexAcquire(myMutex1,osWaitForever);
        _send("Hello form child1\n");
        osMutexRelease(myMutex2);
        osDelay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: "program crashes" is a symptom with many causes.  Do you have any diagnostic information, such as error messages?  Does it end up in an error handler, exception handler,  hardware watchdog reset - any information is more useful than none.  Do you have a debugger - if it hangs, where is it hanging?

Comment: Note that both tasks output identical messages - how do you know which one is running?

Comment: The code that creates the mutex(es), tasks and starts the scheduler would be helpful too  - there are problems with this code for sure, but it is not clear that those issues would cause a "crash" if we don't know the nature of the crash.

Comment: I have my doubts that this is "real" code - the apparent typo in the name `child_tas2` suggests that.  If it is not the _actual_ code that results in the observed error, how do we know this _simplified_ code will reproduce the error at all?  It seems possible in that case that the errors that are certainly in this code are not the same as the errors in the real code, and we are wasting our time.  Please clarify and provide code (simplified or otherwise) that you have built and run and which reproduces the fault.  Then copy and paste that code verbatim, complete and without further modification

Answer (score 0):

Each task acquires `myMutex1` but releases `myMutex2`.  That is certainly wrong, one task will acquire `myMutex1`, and the other will never do so, because it is never released.  That would result in one task becoming permanently blocked and the other running indefinitely, so it is not clear how that would result in a "crash".  More information required to answer that one.  In the code in teh question both tasks output the same message so you would not be able to tell which one was running.

Also there is no purpose in each task having its own mutex as appears you may have intended here (though the previous error makes that uncertain) - that will not protect the resource (which presumably here is whatever `_send()` outputs to?).  You should have one mutex per resource, not one mutex per task.

More plausibly:

```
void child_task1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        osMutexAcquire( myMutex, osWaitForever ) ;

        _send( "Hello from " __FUNCTION__ "\n" ) ;

        osMutexRelease( myMutex ) ;

        osDelay( 100 ) ;
    }
}

void child_task2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        osMutexAcquire( myMutex, osWaitForever ) ;

        _send( "Hello from " __FUNCTION__ "\n" ) ;

        osMutexRelease( myMutex ) ;

        osDelay( 100 ) ;
    }
}
```